# HP Spectre x360 does not wake up from suspend correctly after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, 17.10

Since the upgrade to 17.10, my HP Spectre x360 almost never wakes up from suspend correctly. It sometimes (rarely) does, but most of the time, it reboots. Sometimes, it does not reboot but displays a black or frozen screen, and I have to reboot it manually.

- The problem is *not* related to Wayland, the same happens with Xorg.
- The problem is not related to a particular application,
  it happens even when I close all apps before suspending.

Anyone having the same problem and/or a clue?

Comment: The problem *seems* to have been fixed by the latest update. I suspect this had to do with ``systemd`` (which was part of the update, and is now version 234-2ubuntu12.1). I'll answer my question after a while if the problem does not reappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days without the problem recurring, I confirm the update fixed it. Thanks Ubuntu ;-)

Comment: Problem is back with ubuntu 19.10 and the latest hp spectre x360

Comment: I do not own a HP Spectre anymore, so I won't be able to help, sorry. Not that I had gained much insight from my previous experience, anyway: it had just fixed itself with an update...